# Algorithm to spawn objects randomly

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, overlap

so I'm making a snowboarding game, and as the player rides down I want the terrain to randomly generate. Right now, I'm using this code:

```
void Biome::draw()
{
    srand(seed); // seed is generated elsewhere
    for (int x = 0; x < maxObstAmount; x++)
    {
        int xLoc = rand() % 640;
        int yLoc = rand() % 480;
        int obst = rand()%obstsInBiome.size();
        obstsInBiome[obst].drawObstacle(xLoc, yLoc);
    }
}
```

The function chooses random obstacle in the biome, and spawns it at a random location on the screen, which is essentially what I want. However, this causes objects to overlap, and so forth, so I was just wondering if anyone could help me come up with a better algorithm to spawn them so they don't overlap? Thanks

Comment: what are you stuck on? Can't you just keep a list of all spawned obstacles and have a check based on that before you spawn a new one?

Comment: I thought that cycling through a loop 100+ times every time i spawn a new object would be inefficient, is that not the case?

Comment: if you have 100+ objects on the screen at any given time, looping over an array is going to be the least of your concerns.

Comment: Looping through a list with up to 100 objects 100 or even a few hundred times is going to be lightning-quick. If you want, you can use a `std::set`, which should be a lot faster.

Comment: hm Ok I always thought it'd be bad for some reason, I guess knowing this I can try some more things and see how they go

Comment: You could maybe use a [linear congruential generator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20085386/1679849)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could calculate the regions which you could generate a new object in without overlapping beforehand and use that range to generate the position of the new object.

**EDIT**:

Here is a description of an algorithm I would use given the scenario you described:

I am picturing something like this with an x-y geography.  Where the `o`'s are objects in question.  `C` is the **creation horizon**.

```
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |     o         o
     |          o          o
     |o            o                        <-- Player moves this direction
  ^  |        o    o    o
  |  |  o               o
  y  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     C   x-->
```

If you have only one object per x-position then the problem is fairly trivial.  In the above diagram adjacent `o` are objects with a size in the y-direction.

This is a second diagram to clearly delineate individual objects:

```
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |     7         3
     |          5          1
     |9            4                        <-- Player moves this direction
  ^  |        6    4    2
  |  |  8               2
  y  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     C   x-->
```

1. Generate your first object.
2. Generate the next object in a region not occupied by the previous object.
3. Repeat step 2 as long as you'd like.

If you can have more than one object per x-position, or if the objects have some width in the x-direction:

```
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |     o         o
     |            o          o
     |o         oooo                        <-- Player moves this direction
  ^  |        o       ooo
  |  |  o             ooo
  y  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     C   x-->
```

or

```
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |     7         3
     |     7      5          1
     |     7    4444                        <-- Player moves this direction
  ^  | 88     6       222
  |  | 88             222
  y  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     C   x-->
```

Your overlap problem becomes a bit harder to track, but it still manageable.

1. Generate your first object.
2. Check objects, starting with the immediate previous object until the first object without  dimensions that *interfere* or cross the **creation horizon** `C`, and eliminate the space taken up by them from the choice pool of positions to create your new object.
3. Repeat step 2.

To elaborate on step to I will give an example:

```
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |  
   11|1
   11|1                                     <-- Player moves this direction
  ^  |  
  |  |  
  y  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     C   x-->
```

Say we have this scenario, we have create `object 1`, only a third of this object is even in view yet, but we can see if we create another object before this object comes into view it will be problematic. To avoid an overlap we can choose a random position and width which can exist in the space either above of below `object 1`.  The following would be a valid choice:

```
       |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       |  
      1|11
      1|11                                     <-- Player moves this direction
  ^    |  
  | 22 |  
  y    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       C   x-->
```

A scenario further along could be something like this:

```
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |     33
      |     33           111
     4|4                 111                      <-- Player moves this direction
  ^  4|4          22
  |   |     
  y   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      C   x-->
```

You may not want to place your `object 5` where `object 4` is drawn, but objects `3`, `2`, and `1` are out of the way at this point and don't really need to be considered. So you can have your algorithm check against the last object created, `4`, (and maybe `3` depending on how you  set your game up) and set the creation limits accordingly.

Granted this is a simplified versioning, and I assume you will give yourself much more space to create these objects in I hope this illustrates an algorithm that will solve the problem you are running into.

Comment: The only way i could think of doing this would be to store an objects position in an array everytime I spawn one, and then cycle through the array of already used positions when i spawn a new object, but would cycling through a loop 100+ times every time i spawn a new object be inefficient?

Comment: @RyanMartin I dont think you would need to store a separate array if you already have references these objects, I assume you can access their position and width and simply calculate them on the fly. I do not know how your game is set up but I'm picturing you have some objects coming towards a snowboarder going downhill. You would then only run into an overlap case with the objects that exist at the horizon where you would generate your new objects.  Could you then not need to cycle and check against all 100+ objects but instead just the ones near to said horizon?

Comment: Well I'm planning on the player actually moving downwards, and then the obstacles spawning and the player just passing by them, then they spawn as needed offscreen before the player reaches them. I think I might be able to figure some things out with these ideas, I'll see how things go

Comment: @RyanMartin I included a more complete description of what I commented in an edit.

Comment: Oh my got you are awesome, This helps a bunch bro, I'm sure I can get it working now with this in mind. I appreciate the time you put into this post, it helps a ton. Thanks!